# How to fix slow scrolling when using webkit-transform and relative positioning on the iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, webkit, mobile-safari

I have implemented scrolling of a div by using relative positioning and webkit animation for the iphone, it works beautifully on desktop safari but is choppy on the actual iphone (fine on the simulator).

The scrolling works by having a div nested and clipped (overflow:hidden) by its parent. I then set the top position and animate it with -webkit style declarations.  The iphone seems to  noticeably slow down when there are a lot of items in the inner div.

Any ideas how make the scrolling smoother?

This was a problem with iScroll code and my own hand coded stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using translate3d is much faster than straight up translate, as it utilizes hardware acceleration.

Comment: I could kiss you.  `Translate3d` is at least three gajillion times faster than my `translate` code.  Thank you!